# What is this presumably parasitic plant in an Oak Hickory forest in Eastern Long Island, New York?

Tags: identification, parasites

This small, skinny, plant was found at the Eastern end of Long Island, New York, USA. It was in an Oak Hickory forest.

I believe it's parasitic, meaning it has no chlorophyll and requires a host to reproduce.

Which species is this? Might it be some species of Orobanche?

[image]

Comment: I doubt it is a Orobanche

Comment: > parasitic plant > eastern Long Island *I instantly thought "Shoreham nuclear p!ant"...*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure, I am not from that area. But my two cents are [Indian pipe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotropa_uniflora) (*Monotropa uniflora*), or some related species. They are indeed parasitic, they have no chlorophyll.

Comment: I believe you are right. On another forum someone pointed out that it could be Montropa fruiting. Although I always note the flowering phase, I've never noted it at this phase.

Comment: Yes you (or the other forum) is right, fruiting as seen [here](https://www.flickr.com/photos/22032600@N04/10391238165/) is very similar. Pretty weird plant, almost alien!